# Responsive srcset images by media query?

Tags: srcset

Have I misunderstood the `img srcset` tag if I say that I'd like to specify to the browser what image to show when the screen is `max-size: 599px` (mobile) and when it's above that?

```
<img 
srcset="
    small.jpg 600w,
    big.jpg   2000w"
sizes="
    (max-width: 599px) 600w,
    2000w"
src="big.jpg" alt="Some text" />
```

This code doesn't behave at all how I'd expect it to. I'd like the browser to show the small image when it's a mobile screen, and show the large one for every other device resolution. Is there no way to do this simply? So confusing.

I've read articles on SitePoint, Smashing Mag, etc, and none of them explains it simply as above. They go into image widths, viewports, ratios, etc. All I need is to specify in a media-query screen resolution style which image to show at which resolution.

Many thanks.